# Advanced features with Flutter Driver (or Silenium/Ghost Inspector)

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutterdriver

Looking for a UI integration test strategy for Flutter. We'd love to use Silenium/Ghost Inspector but seems that is not practical due to lack of html id's or CSS classes in Flutter ([Add id or name property or other means of identification for Flutter Web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967096/add-id-or-name-property-or-other-means-of-identification-for-flutter-web-applica)). Or has anyone found a way round that?

In the meantime Flutter Driver has only very basic documentation for simple tests like finding a button and pressing the button. Anyone know if I can do other operations like navigate to a specific page (e.g. using a # url fragment), test a link which leads to an external site, check visual setup of the page against an image, and other such tests which would be standard in Silenium and the like.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well seems Flutter Driver is still very limited so I have instead found a strategy for using Selenium, posted full details here:
[Strategy to use Selenium browser testing with Flutter Web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927762/strategy-to-use-selenium-browser-testing-with-flutter-web-apps/62927763#62927763)